# How to update ToolTip text each time before display?

Tags: mfc, dialog, runtime, tooltip

**How can I make a toolTip text updating itself each time the tooltip is (about to be) displayed ?**

I have a *`CDialog`* derived dialog which uses *`CToolTipCtrl`* tooltips in the usual way and it works just fine:

- *`CToolTipCtrl`* member variable in my *`CDialog`* class.
- created tooltip and added to tool in *`CDialog::OnInitDialog`*
- message relayed to the *`CToolTipCtrl`* in *`CDialog::PreTranslateMessage`*

I also know how to update the toolTip text in various places of the code using *`CToolTipCtrl::UpdateTipText`* and *`CToolTipCtrl::Update`*

However, what I want and have not yet accomplished is this:
**I want that the text of the tooltip updated each time the mouse hoovers over the tool before the according tooltip is displayed**, i.e. the displayed text is dependent on the situation the moment the tooltip-text is displayed.

My working code so far (truncated to relevant lines):

```
class CmyDialog : public CDialog
{
  virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
  virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
  virtual void RefreshToolTipText();        // Want to call this prior each display

  CToolTipCtrl m_toolTip;
}

BOOL CmyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialog::OnInitDialog();
  m_toolTip.Create(this);
  m_toolTip.AddTool( GetDlgItem(IDC_SOMECONTROLID), "Sometext" );
  m_toolTip.Activate( TRUE );
}

BOOL CmyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  if(IsWindow(m_toolTip.m_hWnd)) 
     m_toolTip.RelayEvent(pMsg); 
}

void CmyDialog::RefreshToolTipText()
{
  m_toolTip.UpdateTipText( "updated runtime text",  GetDlgItem(IDC_SOMECONTROLID) );
  m_toolTip.Update();   
}
```

Comment: I think I've found the solution, but as a new user I can't post the answer within the next 6hrs :c). Will do so tomorrow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `CToolTipCtrl::AddTool` use the "special" value `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` as the text to use for the tooltip. This will cause the tooltip to post a `TTN_NEEDTEXT` notification to the *parent* of the window you are adding a tooltip for. The parent can then set the text accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As commented above, I've found a solution which seems to work already. Didn't need to set the LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, maybe it is a default? 


If you have some comments to my solution above, I'd love to hear of them. Still learning...

(PS: Can't upvote your answer with less then 15 rep :c) But thanks!)

Comment: Your solution will work, but generally speaking, the "correct" way to handle it, according to the documentaiton, is to use callbacks and respond to `TTN_NEEDTEXT`. But if your solution works for your purposes, then great! No worries about the upvote - not in it for the votes ;)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have figured it out myself. As I couldn't find the solution online, I'm going to post it here for references. I would still appreciate comments if there are any.

I've added the following line the message map of the *CmyDialog* class:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CmyDialog, CDialog)
   ON_NOTIFY( TTN_SHOW, 0, OnToolTipTextAboutToShow )   
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And I've added the following member function to CmyDialog:

```
void CmyDialog::OnToolTipTextAboutToShow(NMHDR * pNotifyStruct, LRESULT* result)
{
   if ( pNotifyStruct->hwndFrom == m_toolTip.m_hWnd )
       RefreshToolTipText();
}
```

Apparently, the TTN_SHOW notification code gets send via WM_NOTIFY each time a tooltip is about to be displayed. The if-check in my function checks that the toolTip is from the specific CToolTipCtrl.

Comment: Comment: Using m_toolTIP.Update() in RefreshToolTipText() is not a good idea in case the tool-tip window needs to change size (i.e. a multi-line tooltip which changes between 2 and 3 lines.) I had to circumvent this in the code or could see crashes when the codes enters an infinite loop.